# if we increase the doping level of semiconductor susbtrate of a n channel MOSFET, does the Vth, threshold voltage also increase?

Tags: mosfet

A N-Channel MOSFET is a type of MOSFET in which the channel of the MOSFET is composed of a majority of electrons as current carriers. When the MOSFET is activated and is on, the majority of the current flowing are electrons moving through the channel.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question; can you explain what work you have done towards asking it, and what particular problem you are stuck on?